# Masking an image with selectable text with SVG - possible?

Tags: svg, masking

One neat typographic effect often seen headlines in magazines etc, is to select a really bold font and put an image inside of the text. Here's a random example of the effect:
[image]

In web design, there is no way to do this with plain html/css/js. It could be done with flash or with a bitmap image but those techniques obviously have some big drawbacks.

I wonder if it is possible to do this with SVG though? I have never ever used SVG, but if this is possible, it might be worth trying to wrap my head around it.

For instance, would it be possible to let a javascript go through the page and look for certain elements (h1s or certain classes) and generate, on the fly, an SVG file that contains selectable text in the chosen font with an image clipped to the letter shapes? Does anyone know if this has been done, tutorials, anything else that might be interesting for looking at this problem...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible to do this with SVG, though you don't need to do masking, you can just specify the image as a pattern:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
        <image xlink:href="daisy-grass-repeating-background.jpg" x="0" y="0"
            width="600" height="450" /><!-- Image from http://silviahartmann.com/background-tile/6-grass-meadow-tile.php-->
    </pattern>
</defs>
```

Then reference that as the [fill](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#Patterns) in your text:

```
<text fill="url(#img1)">
```

I've done [an example](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/pattern-fill.svg), the most painful part was figuring out what `patternUnits` and `patternContentUnits` actually did, [this MDC article was helpful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Tutorial/Fill_Stroke_and_Gradients#Patterns).

The text is selectable in Opera and Chrome (and, I presume, Safari) ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶F̶i̶r̶e̶f̶o̶x̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶a̶ ̶[l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶b̶u̶g̶](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292498) (bug now fixed, expect it to work in Firefox 24 or so).  SVG doesn't work in IE (until 9 comes out, anyway) so either don't bother with it or see if you can get VML to do similar things.  If you're going to try and build a JavaScript utility to do this a good starting point might be figuring our how to make the above work in [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'll take a long good look at what you did and get my feet wet with svg.

I'm surprised this effect isn't used more if it's that simple; it's such an obvious limitation in the standard css/html possibilities...

Comment: @last-child I think we'll see several SVG features brought into standard HTML/CSS - it's the same rendering engine after all, the code to achieve the effect is already there in most browsers - just like several Canvas features (shadows, transforms) are now part of CSS.

Comment: random [glitch in the svg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504005/svg-text-tspan-isnt-doing-as-its-told) but this is really neat once it's worked around

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
<svg>  
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="textClip">
      <text id="text1" x="20" y="300" style="font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;font-size: 180pt; stroke: black; fill: none;">HEY</text>
    </clipPath>
    <g id="shapes">
      <image id="resultImg"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="520px" height="520px" xlink:href="http://beerhold.it/500/500"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g >
    <use xlink:href="#shapes" style="clip-path: url(#textClip);"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**here is the same in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nedudi/v84p5/1/**