# Pure CSS3 text color gradient - Is it possible?

Tags: colors, css, gradient

**Is there a way to create a cross-browser, pure CSS3 text color gradient?**

So, no png's. No 'webkit' only.

**EDIT:** To be more precise: It's CSS3 only, and it's for text, not box gradients.

**EDIT:** I found **[this solution](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/07/24/pure-css-text-gradient-no-pngs/)**, but it's only for webkit.

Comment: It's easy, you can refer to this article: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient/

Comment: across which browsers? the ones that support CSS3?

Comment: That's limited to box gradient only, I'm afraid. I'm looking for text gradient.

Comment: Is the background a solid color?

Comment: Nah, I forgot that pngs won't do. How about an SVG solution? It's supported by all CSS3 supporting browsers, doesn't need any images and is quite accessible.

Comment: [Here's an SVG example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634663/masking-an-image-with-selectable-text-with-svg-possible/3636303#3636303) - it uses an image rather than an SVG gradient, but that should be easy to change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no cross-browser way to do this outside webkit because only webkit currently has a [background-clip: text](http://webkit.org/blog/164/background-clip-text/), and [this extension to background-clip](http://trentwalton.com/bgclip/) is not on standards track (as far as I am aware). If you want to relax your CSS3 requirement, you can accomplish the same effect cross-browser with Canvas (or SVG), but then you're talking about HTML5-capable browsers only.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "pure" CSS way at the moment, but there is a way using CSS and some duplication of content. See [my server side css gradient text solution here](http://www.bagnall.co.uk/gradient_text.asp), which doesn't require JavaScript or plain background.
You can also do this client side using JavaScript, see what Dragonlabs has done [here](http://labs.dragoninteractive.com/rainbows_article.php).

Comment: Very impressive and intuitive.  Thanks for this option.

Comment: Sorry fo the double comment, but I thought it might be useful to quick add my variation of your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/P8k58/.  I used a few tricks to get it to work correctly and for my purposes I used a text shadow to finish off the effect.  For the purpose of just creating a shine, however, this could easily be done with CSS content only (IE 8+ at best).

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks. And I like your use of :before and :after .

Answer (score 0):

As I've already pointed out as a comment in zzzzBov's response, there is a way to achieve a text gradient in CSS3 only.

If you take the [PNG solution](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect/) a bit further, you can do the same trick with css3 gradients.

Of course this does only work for text that is on a uniform background color.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution at the moment is to use a solid color as non-webkit fallback and then use the following technique ( requires webkit ):

```css
h1 {
  color: $333;
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
```

Comment: I already pointed out that it "requires webkit" .. Did you have a better solution?  Works in FF, Chrome and Safari .. @user2602584 poor user