# css text clipping / masking?

Tags: html, css

I am putting together an idea for a site with scrollable background images, on top there is a white menu div with text in it. If possible i would like to have the text completely see through so that it almost looks like it has cut the text from the white div to show the images.

i know of the css rule:

background-clip: text

but i don't think this wont solve my problem as my images are not the background for the div the text is in. Is there any workaround without using svg or png.

thanks :)

Comment: JSfiddle please but basically unless the images are in the bg of the div I think you are out of luck.

Comment: background-clip works with chrome at this time, look at SVG , it can be done, png will provide an image , wich is fine if you fill the Alt attribute :)

Comment: Seems like this might be part of your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082909/cut-out-text-in-css-possible

Comment: Yeah thanks guys, it looks like my only option is svg :(