# How do I make an overlay be "erased" with text

Tags: html, css, text, background, overlay

It's kind of hard to explain, but I want to make a website with a picture as the background, and over the picture a grey overlay. I then want to have some text above the overlay, and where the text is, the grey overlay is removed, so the text is written in the absence of the grey overlay.

I made an example a year ago, with images, but I want to make it in CSS, if it's possible.
Here's the example (sorry for the mess, didn't really know what I was doing back then)
[Example Page](http://www.rasmusra.dk/overlayexample.html)

Specifically, the text furthest down (most visible) on the page.

I really hope something like this is possible without using images as the text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This could steer you in the right direction? http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageUnderText/ ( http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/ )

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CSS.  You can do it with SVG though:

[Text with image background in svg or css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846504/text-with-image-background-in-svg-or-css)